# npm install - determine the end of the installation

Tags: python, npm, npm-install

Using a python automated tool, I run the command `npm install` followed by `npm run build` in my project to build a .war file and put it in a tomcat server.

I need to run `npm install` every time because I wipe the folder and make a new git clone using Jenkins, **every time**.

The problem is that the python script tries to find a sentence that I determine in advance that will confirm that it can start the next task, but when I run the command `npm install` there is no clean way I can determine that the task is done because that's the end of the output:

```
|   `-- is-buffer@1.1.5
+-- webpack-war-plugin@1.0.0-beta.3
| +-- archiver@1.3.0
| | +-- archiver-utils@1.3.0
| | | +-- glob@7.1.2
| | | `-- lazystream@1.0.0
| | +-- async@2.4.1
| | +-- buffer-crc32@0.2.13
| | +-- glob@7.1.2
| | +-- tar-stream@1.5.4
| | | +-- bl@1.2.1
| | | `-- end-of-stream@1.4.0
| | +-- walkdir@0.0.11
| | `-- zip-stream@1.1.1
| |   `-- compress-commons@1.2.0
| |     `-- crc32-stream@2.0.0
| |       `-- crc@3.4.4
| `-- typescript@2.3.4
+-- whatwg-fetch@1.1.1
`-- write@0.3.3
`-- fs-exists-sync@0.1.0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

But the output is not always going to be the same. All I am looking for is a way to properly know that the command is done like: `npm installation completed`. Unless there is a better way to do it. (It has to work on windows and linux)

Comment: What's wrong with just waiting for the `npm install` process to exit? e.g., what `suprocess.call()` or `proc.wait()` does?

Comment: The python tool I am using logs the output of the command into a file and waits until it finds a predetermined string in that file before it starts the next command

Comment: I unfortunately do not have the choice. Thank you for suggesting something better instead of just saying it was poorly designed.

Comment: I can't make a suggestion without knowing all your requirements. With what is present in your question, all you need is a two line shell script with `npm install; npm run build`, but obviously I don't have all the details.

Comment: So I could have a bat file that has both commands and have them both log in the same file and then validate when the build is done ? (Validating that `npm run build` is over is much simpler.

Comment: It should be done when the process exits, unless you are doing something inside of the build code to background itself. There should be no need to check logs.

Comment: Can't you do something like `npm install &&  node -e 'console.log("\n\nnpm install finished")'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print `npm install done` at the end of `npm install`'s output into a log file:

```
npm install >> D:\npmInstall.log 2>&1 && echo npm install done >> D:\npmInstall.log 2>&1
```